# How can GTIN be used in blockchain?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I am using hyperledger fabric to be able to trace products to check its provenance within a supply chain. This project is meant for a lot of products, especially for longer periods of time.

I am having trouble figuring out what kind of identifiers to use for identifying a product which needs to be transacted in the blockchain. All the data will be stored within it forever.

According to a source (https://www.gs1ca.org/files/How_to_Create_a_GTIN.pdf) I can only make a max amount of 100.000 unique codes per company. After that I am geussing it needs to be reused. What are the identifiers I can use for basically an unlimitted amount of unique-codes within blockchain? Are there standards to handle this? Or should I identify my assets with two identifiers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event a company exhausts their 100,000 GTIN's they can apply for a second, or a third, or so on, GS1 Prefix. So essentially you should map their GTIN's along with their GS1 prefix.

Do some research on IBM FoodTrust, it is the most well known GS1 standard-based system for tracking goods on a Blockchain (Hyperledger).